# Umbraco IContentFinder Virtual Node

Tags: umbraco

I'm trying to load a node under a diffrent parent through the IContentFinder. I can locate the correct node by useing some kind of wildcard system.

So an example:

> www.example.com/group1/overview/id
>
> www.example.com/globalOverview/id

The node from group1 can be shown with the correct URL in the global overview. The downside is that the parent is the group overview instead of the globalOverview. This will screw up the breadcrumb and other parent related things.

Is there any way to change the node it's parent for only that request. Or assign a virutal Path/Parent. If there are other posibilities shoot!

Cheers, Tom

---

*Umbraco Forum [post](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions//67450-icontentfinder-virtual-node)*

*Umbraco 7.2.x*

Comment: Do you intend there to be a slash (/) between global and overview (e.g www.example.com/global/overview/id)?

Comment: No, globalOverview is a node not listed under a group. It is encapsulating all group elements listed under the overview.

Edit: Note that if it is listed as global/overview/id the same problem occurs

Comment: I wonder of using URL rewriting or maybe https://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbraco-best-practices/umbracourlalias would be a direction to research.

Comment: It is not about rewriting the url. It is about changing the node it's parent or create some kind of virtual node to act under a diffrent parent. So a child note from group1 overview can be listed under the global overview but not  with the group1 overview as parent.